# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified at OCI call OCIServerAttach

Tags: oracle, repository, oracle12c, obiee, oracle-bi

I am working on OBIEE-12c. My db is also Oracle-12c. During repository creation i am getting following error.

```
[nQsError:17014] Could not connect to Oracle database.
[nQsError:17001] Oracle Error code: 12154, message: ORA-12154:
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
at OCI call OCIServerAttach.
```

[image: Obiee repository creation error]

Comment: 1. Is listener of DB you're connecting up and running? 2. Is TNS_ADMIN variable pointing to proper location of tnsnames.ora? 3. Does tnsnames.ora contain TNS entry for DB you're trying to connect?

Comment: Yes all of your points you are saying are done on my side moreover i have  made tnsping to my service and it is also working.

Comment: I have connected now through this string localhost:1521\pdborcl. make sure with slash if it is / or \.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the full connection string, as it appears in the tnsnames.ora file, instead of just the name??

Instead of writing `pdborcl` write:

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl))
  )
```

Or whatever your connect string looks like.

I'm not sure why that happens but i couldn't make my work until I did that.

Comment: I have connected now through this string localhost:1521\pdborcl. make sure with slash if it is / or \.

Answer (score -1):

to resolve the issue, try the following

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = <what ever SID you specified>)))
log : anonymous
P/w : < the password you specified when creating the Database>
```

Comment: Exactly the same answer as given by @Lando, 4 months ago.